# How to forward URL to a subfolder on network

Tags: apache-2.2

•I have installed apache on CentOS five.

•I have registered a domain name at namecheap.com

When I type the URL in the web browser, I would like it to redirect to a directory within the website.

Currently, it just goes to /var/www/html.

I would like the site to go to /var/www/html/website1 instead so I could host two websites on the same server.

How would I do this?

Currently, it works if I go to **my_ip_adress/website1** but I would like website1 folder to be the parent directory for the particular website.

Comment: This is the most basic of web server configuration.  You really need to do your homework before posting a question like this here.

Comment: Basic to you, I haven't even really messed with linux before.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be rude.  But ServerFault expects you to do your research first, and show us what you've tried.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Create [Virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)
2. change [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot)

Something like:

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
  DocumentRoot /www/docs/host.example.com
  ServerName host.example.com
  ErrorLog logs/host.example.com-error_log
  TransferLog logs/host.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

as per Apache documentation.